# something strange with textBoxes after postback

Tags: asp.net, postback

I wrote little program, which creates three textBoxes in each row after click button. Each click calls method `createControl` which creates `rows[0..n-1]` with textboxes and then in method `Button_Click` adds `row[n]`. So, when I have for example 1 and more rows with textboxes with some text in them and then click on button, after postback I get strange situation with information in textboxes: in `row(n-1)` only first textbox has text, and other 2 - doesn't have.

For instance, I have 3 rows with text:

```
1 1 1
2 2 2
3 3 3
```

and then click add button:

```
(1)       (1)     (1)
(2)       (2)     (2)
(3,3,3)   (empty) (empty)
```

and new empty row
So, in `(n-1)` row in first textbox I get three value, why?

```
    TextBox[] textbox;
    TextBox[] textbox2;
    TextBox[] textbox3;

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (IsPostBack)
        {
            createControls();
        }
        else
        {
            Num = 0;
        }
    }

    private int Num
    {
        get { return (int)ViewState["num"]; }
        set { ViewState["num"] = value; }
    }

    private void createControls()
    {
        textbox = new TextBox[Num + 1];
        textbox2 = new TextBox[Num + 1];
        textbox3 = new TextBox[Num + 1];
        for (int i = 0; i < Num; i++)
        {
            textbox[i] = new TextBox();
            textbox[i].ID = "textbox[" + i + "]";
            PlaceHolder1.Controls.Add(textbox[i]);
            textbox2[i] = new TextBox();
            textbox2[i].ID = "textbox2[" + i + "]";
            PlaceHolder1.Controls.Add(textbox2[i]);
            textbox3[i] = new TextBox();
            textbox3[i].ID = "textbox3[" + i + "]";
            PlaceHolder1.Controls.Add(textbox3[i]);
        }
    }

    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        textbox[Num] = new TextBox();
        textbox[Num].ID = "textbox[" + Num + "]";
        PlaceHolder1.Controls.Add(textbox[Num]);
        textbox2[Num] = new TextBox();
        textbox2[Num].ID = "textbox[" + Num + "]";
        PlaceHolder1.Controls.Add(textbox2[Num]);
        textbox3[Num] = new TextBox();
        textbox3[Num].ID = "textbox[" + Num + "]";
        PlaceHolder1.Controls.Add(textbox3[Num]);
        Num++;
    }
```

Comment: Why are you using arrays of Textboxes?

Comment: how is it possible in other way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are creating textboxes with same ID inside Button1_Click.

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    textbox[Num] = new TextBox();
    textbox[Num].ID = "textbox[" + Num + "]";
    PlaceHolder1.Controls.Add(textbox[Num]);
    textbox2[Num] = new TextBox();
    textbox2[Num].ID = "textbox[" + Num + "]"; // Must be "textbox2[" + Num + "]"
    PlaceHolder1.Controls.Add(textbox2[Num]);
    textbox3[Num] = new TextBox();
    textbox3[Num].ID = "textbox[" + Num + "]"; // Must be "textbox3[" + Num + "]"
    PlaceHolder1.Controls.Add(textbox3[Num]);
    Num++;
}
```

### Update:

Actually, you do not need TextBox arrays.

```
private int Num
{
    get { return Convert.ToInt32(ViewState["num"] ?? "0"); }
    set { ViewState["num"] = value; }
}

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (IsPostBack)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < Num; i++)
            CreateTextBoxes(i);
    }
}

protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    CreateTextBoxes(Num++);
}

protected void CreateTextBoxes(int id)
{
    PlaceHolder1.Controls.Add(new TextBox {ID = "textbox1" + id});

    PlaceHolder1.Controls.Add(new TextBox {ID = "textbox2" + id});

    PlaceHolder1.Controls.Add(new TextBox {ID = "textbox3" + id});
}
```

Comment: exactly! I was in a hurry and did this stupid mistake. Thanks!

Comment: It happens. :) I also updated the code which is less error prone.